# git config issue on another drive

Tags: windows, git, config

So I have setup a git config to have a work folder and a personal folder:

- It work fine for my personal folder witch is on my C drive (NTFS), it use my personal@email.com
- Not for my work folder witch is on my D drive (FAT32), it use the default@email.com (located in my .gitconfig) but didn't used my work@email.com

Is my use case even possible? I don't have found a tutorial with another drive as the C. Maybe git want the same drive as the one with the exe? Would be nice if someone has getting something like this working.

Here it is my .git config (I've tested to inverse the order of the two and that changed nothing)

```ini
[user]
    email = default@gmail.com
    name = Default

[includeIf "gitdir/i:D:/Work/**"]
    path = ~/.gitconfig-work
[includeIf "gitdir/i:C:/Personal/**"]
    path = ~/.gitconfig-personal
```

Here is my .gitconfig-work

```ini
[user]
    email = work@email.com
    name = Work
```

Here is my .gitconfig-personal

```ini
[user]
    email = personal@email.com
    name = Personal
```

I've tried calling .gitconfig-work on a path on the C drive and it work so the problem should not be the .gitconfig-work. To be precise I've changed to something like this and it work (I got the work@email.com) :

```ini
[includeIf "gitdir/i:C:/Personal/**"]
    path = ~/.gitconfig-work
```

So here it is the result of my Personal config (This one works : it use my personal@email.com)

```
PS C:\Personal> mkdir test

    Directory: C:\Personal

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----           10/2/2023 12:17 AM                test

PS C:\Personal> cd .\test\
PS C:\Personal\test> git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Personal/test/.git/
PS C:\Personal\test> git config --show-origin --get user.email
file:C:/Users/Sacha/.gitconfig-personal        personal@email.com
PS C:\Personal\test>
```

And this one is the result for my Work config and it didn't (it use default@email.com)

```
PS D:\Work> mkdir test

    Directory: D:\Work

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----           10/2/2023 12:16 AM                test

PS D:\Work> cd .\test\
PS D:\Work\test> git init
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/Work/test/.git/
PS D:\Work\test> git config --show-origin --get user.email
file:C:/Users/Sacha/.gitconfig  default@gmail.com
PS D:\Work\test>
```

By the way, my D drive is a partition on another(physically) drive in FAT32, I need to have my work on this drive since my D drive is a shared partition with a Pop OS 22.04 I need my two Os to access this folder.

```
Git : git version 2.40.1.windows.1
Windows Version: 22H2
```

I've tested when assigning a true path to my D drive (so I could use it like C:/Shared) but didn't changed anythings.

Thanks to all people that will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you want more info, here is the github issue I've made : https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/4621

This a quick answer, you need to have sufficent access right in that repo, so by adding this in your .gitconfig, you should be able to get this working :

```ini
[safe]
   directory = *
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you refer to use the same config file to both config (win/linux)? Consider the path format of these OS. win uses " \ " and linux "/" it may be the problem. At least i have not other idea of any incompatibility.

Comment: No it is only on windows here, I don't need to have both work and personal account on my linux. And I used only '/' since git wasn't happy with my '\'.

Comment: ok, I have not more ideas... sorry